# Laravel Job not queued?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm new in Laravel and i want to import a `Csv` file and store the data in DB with `Maatwebsite\Excel`. I'm trying to achieve that using `jobs` in laravel. When i run `php artisan queue:work` i don't see the job in the queue.

I've set my routes :

```js
Route::get('/import', 'UserImportController@getImport')->name('import');
Route::post('/import_process', 'UserImportController@fileImport')->name('import_process');
```

I have my controller like this :

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CsvImportRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Imports\UsersImport;

class UserImportController extends Controller
{
    public function getImport()
    {
        return view('import');
    }

    public function fileImport(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'import_file' => 'required',
        ]);

        Excel::import(new UsersImport, request()->file('import_file'));

        return back()->withStatus('Import done!');
    }


}
```

I've configured my `.env` like this:

```js
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

I've created a Job:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Imports\UsersImport;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class ImportJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Batchable, Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $uploadFile;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($uploadFile)
    {
        $this->uploadFile = $uploadFile;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Excel::import(new UsersImport, $this->uploadFile);
    }
}
```

I created a `Livewire` component and view:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Jobs\ImportJob;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Import extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $batchId;
    public $importFile;
    public $importing = false;
    public $importFilePath;
    public $importFinished = false;

    public function import()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'importFile' => 'required',
        ]);

        $this->importing = true;
        $this->importFilePath = $this->importFile->store('imports');

        $batch = Bus::batch([
            new ImportJob($this->importFilePath),
        ])->dispatch();

        $this->batchId = $batch->id;
    }

    public function getImportBatchProperty()
    {
        if (!$this->batchId) {
            return null;
        }

        return Bus::findBatch($this->batchId);
    }

    public function updateImportProgress()
    {
        $this->importFinished = $this->importBatch->finished();

        if ($this->importFinished) {
            Storage::delete($this->importFilePath);
            $this->importing = false;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.import');
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="import" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" wire:model="importFile" class="@error('import_file') is-invalid @enderror">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Import</button>
        @error('import_file')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </form>

    @if($importing && !$importFinished)
        <div wire:poll="updateImportProgress">Importing...please wait.</div>
    @endif

    @if($importFinished)
        Finished importing.
    @endif
</div>
```

But when i click on `import` button nothing happens the `import` function isn't called and the job is not queued. I don't know what the issue ?

Comment: have you checked that  the function is called?

Comment: @JEJ I have and it's not called.

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear`   and check again

Comment: I did that many times but nothing happens

Comment: its  too hard to find the issue only by reading a since its huge .. you can debug your code using laravel `log::info()` method . use this  check the workflow is right and where the execution fails.. example
`if($someCondition){ Log::info('inside if loop'); $a= $b+$c; Log::info($a.'is the value');}`
hope it will help you to find where is the error..

Comment: You can find your logs in `storage->logs->laravel.logs`

Comment: Probably worth separating the steps. I'd add a `dd('import called')` at the top of that `import` method to establish whether Livewire actually calls the method. If it does, then I'd look at creating a test route that dispatches a job to confirm my queue configuration is all good.